# ReactJS Simulate change value / unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, input, reactjs, reference

i try to simulate a test of a value change on my InputText component. I really don't know how to make that. I just know I must use the ref and the onChange method. But when I put a ref on my test I got an error like "you might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's render method".

Edit = I give a ref in the render of my InputText component

This is the render of my InputText component

```
        render: function () {
        console.log('passerender');


        var attrs = this.generateAttributes();


        var type = this.props.area ? "textarea" : "text";

        return (
            <Input
                className={this.props.menuClassName}
                type={type}
                {...attrs}
                {...this.props.evts}
                className={this.props.menuClassName}
                onChange = {this.handleChange}
                onBlur = {this.handleBlur}
                value={this.state.value}
                ref = "InputField"
                hasFeedback
            />
        );
    }
});
```

This is my test page of my InputText component:

```
        var React = require('react'),
    InputText = require('../resources/assets/js/testcomponents/InputText.js').InputTextEditable,
    TestUtils = require('react-addons-test-utils'),
    ReactDOM = require('react-dom');


describe('InputText', function () {

    var InputElement = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <InputText
            area={false}
            //evts={{onChange: handleChange}}
            attributes={{
                                label:'Test Input Isole',
                                name:'InputTextArea',
                                value: '',
                                wrapperClassName: 'col-md-4',
                                labelClassName: 'col-md-2',
                                groupClassName: 'row'
                                }}
            //ref="InputField"
            editable={true}/>);

    var DomElement = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(InputElement);
    var inputV = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(InputElement.refs.InputField);

    var input = DomElement.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    var inputspan = DomElement.getElementsByTagName('span')[1];


    it('updates input value on key press', function () {
        inputV.value = 'test';
        expect(input.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('');
        TestUtils.Simulate.change(inputV);
        TestUtils.Simulate.keyDown(inputV, {key: "Entrer", keyCode: 13, which: 13});
        expect(input.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('test');
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`findRenderedComponentWithType`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#findrenderedcomponentwithtype) or [`findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag)

You don't need to call `findDOMNode` explicitly, because [`TestUtils`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src%2Ftest%2FReactTestUtils.js#L505) has done this for you.

```
var InputElement = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
    <InputText {...yourProps}/>
);

// Assuming there is only one <input /> DOM element in your Input
var input = TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(InputElement, Input)

// or you can just find <input /> directly
var input = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(InputElement, 'input');

TestUtils.Simulate.change(input);
TestUtils.Simulate.keyDown(input, {key: "Entrer", keyCode: 13, which: 13});
```

Comment: Thank you! But now i got this on my console :  Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: invalid

Comment: @kMM Try to remove {...yourProps}

Comment: @kMM Do you mind to provide which line throws the syntax error?

Comment: When I use TestUtils.Simulate.change(input);

Comment: It is weird. What is your react version?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I find the problem of the syntax error. It was on my html5validator on my input mixin. I put a try/catch to solve this :

```
 var html5Validity = true;
        if (DOM !== undefined) {
            try {
                html5Validity = $(DOM).find(':invalid').length == 0;
                console.log('passe');
            } catch (e) {
                console.log('html5Validity = [catch]');
                html5Validity = true;
            }
        }
        attrs = _.extend({'data-valid': validation.isValid && html5Validity}, attrs);
```

Now it's OK ! Thank you ! :)

Comment: Good to know. IMHO it would be better to use a high-order component rather than use a mixin.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will try this next time